# Starting a tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to get started and make a program with tkinter GUI.

I learned a bit of tkinter in college but it has been a long time since then, and to be honest I haven't retained any knowledge about it. After re-reading documentation on tkinter, I'm convinced that it's hopeless because I'm not sure what tkinter types I have to work with in order to get my program to behave how I want (mostly because I'm trying to deal with images)

The ultimate (simplified) goal of my program is to place a game board as a background image (background.gif or something) and, on top of those images, place another image when a user clicks on that screen region.

I experimented around with create_image but for some reason I can't get it to work. And even if I did get it work, I'm not exactly sure how you would draw an image on top of another image on tkinter?

I guess my main question would be: how do I make it so I can create a background image, but also place widgets/other images on top of that very image canvas? Or should I use labels/frames?

Experimental code that doesn't work (does anyone know why?)

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.resizable(width=tk.FALSE, height=tk.FALSE)
        self.start_GUI();
        self.root.mainloop();

    def start_GUI(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master = self.root, width = 734, height = 429)
        self.canvas.pack(expand = tk.YES, fill = tk.BOTH)
        gif1 = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'background.gif')
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = gif1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rootstart = GUI();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have a problem with displaying images ( I assume they are not visible) is that `gif1` is a local variable. once `start_GUI` finishes its execution, `gif1` is out of scope, and image is deleted. So you dont see any image, because there is no image to be seen anyway. You need to keep references to image objects life though execution of your program. The simples way in your example, would be to make them instance variables, e.g.

```
self.gif1 = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'background.gif')
self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.gif1)
```

To draw new image on top, you just do same, e.g.

```
self.gif2 = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'some_foreground_image.gif')
self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.gif2)
```